# one eventListener for different targets

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, for-loop

I want to have only one event listener that work with 3 different buttons: btn1, btn2, btn3.

I know that "btn+i" doesn't exist and doesn't work. Theres any way to do this? Sorry, I'm a beginner...

```
for(var i:uint=1;i<4;i++){
    btn+i.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do `this["btn" +i]`.

But you'd probably be better off stuffing them all into an array and accessing them that way. Then your code isn't so dependent on everything being named a certain way.

Something like this:

```
var buttons:Array = [btn1, btn2, btn3];
for(var i:int = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClicked);
}
```